# Google TTS client library parameter setting for Chinese language

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I try texttospeech with Google cloud API,Here is the sample code and it works well for English;But when I change language_code='en-US' to 'zh-CN' and set input text to be chinese word,show the Error:
400 No TTS voice matching the TTS request. Please correct the voice selection params and try again.

```
import argparse
# [START tts_synthesize_text]
def synthesize_text(text):
    """Synthesizes speech from the input string of text."""
    from google.cloud import texttospeech
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

    input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)

# Note: the voice can also be specified by name.
# Names of voices can be retrieved with client.list_voices().
    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code='en-US',
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

    response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)

    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
# [END tts_synthesize_text]
```

Please help how to set the parameter when I using Chinese language ?

Comment: From the Google Cloud website,It seems doesn`t support Chinese voice API yet.

Comment: have u solved the problem? i am trying google's tts with chinese and encountered the same problem as well. I am not very experienced to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I use gTTS package to solve this problem and it works for me,here is the code:

```
def text_to_speech_gtts(res_ans):
    from gtts import gTTS
    volume=1.0
    music_file="ans01.mp3"
    tts = gTTS(text=res_ans, lang='zh-tw')
    tts.save(music_file)
    freq = 25000    # audio CD quality
    bitsize = -16    # unsigned 16 bit
    channels = 2     # 1 is mono, 2 is stereo
    buffer = 2048    # number of samples (experiment to get best sound)
    pg.mixer.init(freq, bitsize, channels, buffer)
    # volume value 0.0 to 1.0
    pg.mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    try:
        pg.mixer.music.load(music_file)
    except pg.error:
        print("File {} not found! ({})".format(music_file, pg.get_error()))

    pg.mixer.music.play()
    while pg.mixer.music.get_busy():
        # check if playback has finished
        clock.tick(30) #
    pg.mixer.music.stop()
    pg.mixer.quit()
```